# Filtering data in QGIS

Tags: qgis, filter

I'm working with a dataset of buildings and have catergorised them by their function (gebruikersfunctie). The list of diffetent functions is too big however, so I want to add certain values together with the help of a filter.

For example I want to get two layers, one with gebruikersfunctie being just 'woonfunctie' and one with the values containting 'woonfucntie' (so like 'woonfunctie,winkelfunctie') exept the ones with the exact value 'woonfunctie'.

Right now I'm doing it by hand since the operator LIKE doesn't give me the results I want because I already have the NOT operator stating gebruiksfunctie is not woonfucntie.

Anyone know how to do this more effectively?

[image]

Comment: So, one layer/selection should contain all features with the exact value `woonfunctie`, and the other all other features? Why dont you create a category for `woonfunctie` and put everything else in the other?

Comment: what's wrong with the `like`? `like but not equal` is valid